# PyTorch TypeError: flatten() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to run this program in PyTorch which is custom:

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten(start_dim=1)
        self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2142, 51),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(51, 1)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.flatten(x)
        logits = self.linear_relu_stack(x)
        return logits

model = NeuralNetwork().to(device)
```

The above code is the custom NeuralNetwork. I defined the training loop below.

```
def train_loop(data, y, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        # Compute model prediction and loss
        pred = model(data[i, :, :])
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y[i, :])

        # Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
        print("Loss: {}".format(loss.item()))
```

The following is how I would like to train it

```
final_data = torch.randn(500, 42, 51)
final_output = torch.randn(500, 1)
learning_rate = 1e-3
batch_size = 1
epochs = 5
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

epochs = 10
for t in range(epochs):
    print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
    train_loop(final_data, final_output, model, loss_fn, optimizer)

print('Done!!')
```

The variable `final_data` is of shape 500x42x51. The variable `final_output` is of shape 500x1.
I have been trying to run the above data for 10 epochs but I always end up with this error:

```
Epoch 1
-------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-3fb934698ecf> in <module>()
      9 for t in range(epochs):
     10     print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
---> 11     train_loop(final_data, final_output, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
     12 
     13 print('Done!!')

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/flatten.py in forward(self, input)
     38 
     39     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
---> 40         return input.flatten(self.start_dim, self.end_dim)
     41 
     42     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

TypeError: flatten() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

The output is basically a classification between 0 or 1.
I am still a newbie in terms of PyTorch and would like some help solving this issue and understanding what's wrong.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a bit misleading, if you try running the code from a fresh kernel, the issues are elsewhere...

There are multiple issues with your code:

- You are not using the correct shape for the target tensor `y`, here it should have a single dimension since the output tensor is two-dimensional.
- The target tensor should be of *dtype* `Long`
- When iterating over you data and selecting input (and target) with `data[i, :, :]` (and `y[i, :]`), you are essentially removing the batch axis. However all builtin `nn.Module` work with a batch axis. You can do a slice to avoid that side effect: with `data[i:i+1]` and `y[i:i+1]` respectively. *Also do note that `x[j, :, :]` is identical to `x[j]`.*

That being said, the usage of the cross-entropy loss is not justified. You are outputting a single logit, so it doesn't make sense to use a cross-entropy loss.

- You can either output two logits on the last layer of your model,
- or switch to another loss function such as a binary cross-entropy loss (either using [`nn.BCELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html) or a [`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](http://nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss) which includes a sigmoid activation).

  In this case the target vector should be of *dtype* float, and its shape should equal that of `pred`.

---

```
def train_loop(data, y, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        pred = model(data[i:i+1])
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y[i:i+1].float())
        # [...]

final_data = torch.randn(500, 42, 51)
final_output = torch.randint(0, 2, (500,1))
loss_fn = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
```

Then the following will work:

```
>>> train_loop(final_data, final_output, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your time. My output is basically of shape 500x1 consisting of either 0's or 1's.  So for each input of shape 42x51 I have an associated output of either 0 or 1. I have tried making those changes but I get the same error.

Comment: Since my data was originally a numpy.ndarray, I changed the data using torch.from_numpy(). I realized I was able to solve the error by this. But it gives me a new error:

RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Double

Comment: Thank you! Your changes have helped me to solve it. I just had to convert the input also into float. Though I am not sure if it was the right approach

Comment: Did you switch to `BCEWithLogitsLoss`?

Comment: Yes. I switched to BCEWithLogitsLoss!